# Maximum number of channels in snowpipe streaming

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowpipe

I am wondering the maximum number of channels in snowpipe streaming.

I think that there is no limitation but, when I did experiments, some errors such as back off exception occurred when large number of channels are created.

When I typed `show channels` in the web, there is `10,000` channels I can see.
So I also suspect that the maximum number of channels in 10,000.

Which assumption is correct?

Comment: Nope. 10k is the default (hardcoded?) limit for the number of rows of the result set that are shown in the web UI (snowsight). So if there are more than 10k channels it will simply not show them and you have to look at a subset via `show channels like 'predicate'`, `show channels in database XZY`, etc..